# In android studio,I can't run the App at my smartphone but can run at emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

> Installation failed with message null.
>
> It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>   WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!   Do you want
>   to uninstall the existing application?

when i click OK the message

> DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
>   Error while Installing APK

Comment: clear some space in device then try again

Comment: uninstall app from device and try to reinstall

Comment: In my smartphone space is large enough,So ...

Comment: My phone don't have that app .So I run frist time !

Comment: Have you checked your app's package in Settings.

Comment: Thant for yours answers.but that ways can't solve this problem.

Comment: How to check the app's package in Setting,Check what?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to download the Usb debugger of specific Mobile version then it will run smoothly.Hope it helps you ! Check this link it will guide you :[Run Mobile as emulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb2olFyoMV4):